# How to map an abstract class or interface in Hibernate HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Imagine that I have a `Debtor` class. With Hibernate, I will define the class like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_DEBTOR")
public class Debtor {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_DEBTOR")
    private String idDebtor;
    ...
```

My DAO will then looks like:

```
public class DebtorDaoImpl implements DebtorDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Debtor> findAllDebtors() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("select d from Debtor d");
        return (List<Debtor>) q.getResultList();
    }
```

This works well. However, I am in a configuration where I need to access differents schemas (as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662427/how-to-handle-several-db-schemas-with-hibernate)). Of course, in each schema the table that hosts the debtor list has not the same name. In addition to that, they may not have the exact same structure. That why I have *x* differents `Debtor` class (where *x* is the number of schemas I manipulate).

In the case where I have two differents schemas, I will have two different `Debtor` class: `DebtorOne` and `DebtorTwo`.
As I want to ease my developments, I created an Interface (or an Abstract class, it does not change my problem here) that is implemented by both `DebtorOne` and `DebtorTwo`:

```
public interface Debtor {

    String getIdDebtor();

}
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_DEBTOR_ONE")
public class DebtorOne implements Debtor {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_DEBTOR")
    private String idDebtor;
    ...
```

If I let my DAO as it is, I get the following error from Hibernate:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Debtor is not mapped [select d from Debtor d]
```

If I change my DAO to have this:

```
    public List<Debtor> findAllDebtors() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("select d from DebtorOne d");
        return (List<Debtor>) q.getResultList();
    }
```

then it works, but it is specific to `DebtorOne` schema...

One solution I see is to define a named query on the `DebtorOne` and `DebtorTwo` classes and call this named query from my DAO.
In others words:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_DEBTOR_ONE")
@NamedNativeQueries( { @NamedNativeQuery(name = "findAllDebtors", query = "select d from DebtorOne d") })
public class DebtorOne implements Debtor {
```

and in the DAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Debtor> findAllDebtors() {
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("findAllDebtors");
    return (List<Debtor>) q.getResultList();
}
```

I didn't try it yet, but I think it will work...

*EDIT* I just tried, this will work... except that the `NamedQuery` must be named differently for `DebtorOne` and `DebtorTwo`...

However, I am wondering if there is a way to solve my problem without using the latter solution?

---

**Edit** regarding the first answer, which suggests to use the `@MappedSuperclass`. This annotation seems to be the perfect solution for me, but I think I forgot something, as I still get the same error.

The main `Debtor`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Debtor {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IDDEBTOR")
    protected String idDebtor; // With getter and setter

}
```

one of the extended `Debtor` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEBTOR_ONE")
public class DebtorOne extends Debtor {

...
```

and in my DAO:

```
public List<Debtor> findAllDebtors() {
    return (List<Debtor>) em.createQuery("select d from Debtor d").getResultList();
}
```

is still returning me the error `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Debtor is not mapped [select d from Debtor d]`

What did I miss this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible with an interface, but only with a common abstract base class, that will be annotated with @MappedSuperclass (see Hibernate documentation for further details)

Answer (score 0):

I think for this to work you'd either have to actually map the `Debtor` table to a table or use the table per class strategy (union-subclass). `@MappedSuperClass` only seems to implement a very rudimentary mechanism to copy properties and wouldn't work because you can't query for instances of the superclass.

I take it from the link that you already have something in place to avoid mapping `DebtorTwo` in the hibernate session for the schema of `DebtorOne` (otherwise querying `Debtor` would pull in all records, including ones from the `DebtorTwo` table that wouldn't exist). In that case, follow the [example from the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete) to map the subclass for either case.