# Is there a way to set hibernate catalog from .properties file?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a java/spring/hibernate project that uses two different schemas on a same database server (second schema is read-only). I've set up a database.properties file that defines names of both schemas:

```
default.catalog=testdb1
db2.catalog=testdb2
```

And in the ApplicationContext.xml I can set the default schema from the properties file as such:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties"><props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.default_catalog">${default.catalog}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
    </props>
```

But the problem is that I currently have a few hibernate objects that need to access both schemas. In order to achieve this I've used the 'catalog' property to define the second schema to the hibernate mappings  like such:

DBObjectXX.hbm.xml

```
<class name="fi.company.project.object.DBObjectXX" table="TestTableFromDB1">
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="ID"/>
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
<join table="TestTableFromDB2" catalog="testdb2"> <-- Change this ..
            <key column="ID" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
            <property name="propertyYY" type="string">
                <column name="PropertyYY" not-null="true"/>
            </property>
</join>
</class>
```

This works fine as it is. But every now and then I need to chane the schema names (in testing for example) and I have to do it by search & replacing every mapping file. What I would like to do is to have the schema name come from the database.properties file like such:

```
<class name="fi.company.project.object.DBObjectXX" table="TestTableFromDB1">
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="ID"/>
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
<join table="TestTableFromDB2" catalog="${db2.catalog}"> <-- .. to this or something similar
            <key column="ID" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
            <property name="propertyYY" type="string">
                <column name="PropertyYY" not-null="true"/>
            </property>
</join>
</class>
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662427/how-to-handle-several-db-schemas-with-hibernate

Comment: The suggested solution in the question you are referring to does not help in my situation as I need to access BOTH schemas in that hibernate mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unfortunately have the same SessionFactory with two different schemas. There is on other option you have to use two SessionFactories.

I also don't understand why you cannot use two different SessionFactories if you can have two different schemas.

If this is however true then dude you need seriously reconsider you application design and architecture...

Comment: As I tried to explain in my previous comment, the hibernate object in question (and a few others hibernate objects) are mapped partly from one schema and partly from another. This the reason we cannot use the two session factories. This two schema situation is a given architecture and unfortunately cannot be changed at the moment. I'll revise the question to better emphasise this.

Comment: Across tables it is possible, across databases I highly doubt it. You only solution will be to use two session factories get the objects separately and combine them to create another object manually in your data access layer..