# HQL Query doing joins from different schemas

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

Is there a way (and if there is, how? ;) to create a query in Hibernate (HQL, JPQL) that does the same to

```
select d.name, d.breed, f.amout 
     from dog as d, stocks.food as f
     where f.breed = d.breed
```

That is, there is a user/schema (Animals) and a different one (Stocks) which I would like to join. Is there a way of doing this with HQL?

Thanks.

Comment: this may be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662427/how-to-handle-several-db-schemas-with-hibernate or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877734/hibernate-using-two-different-database-schemas-in-the-same-application